# File not found exception inside php class

Tags: php, class, path, fopen, file-not-found

Hello and thanks for your time.
I have a problem with the following code:

```
//reads all the data from $fileName and returns it
private function readFile($fileName)
{
    $location = $this->path.$fileName;
    try{//try to open file
        $file=fopen($location,"r");
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        return $e;
    }

    $return = "";//read file contents
    while (!feof($file))
    {
        $return .= fgetc($file);
    }

    //close file and return result
    fclose($file);

    return $return;
}
```

I have this function in a class, but every time i call fopen it throws the following exception:

```
Warning: readfile(messages.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\zdupp\php\textChat.php on line 85
```

But I checked the $location var and it is ok("../chat/1.2/messages.txt");

Also the file is there. I also tried a path starting from C:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/zdupp/chat/1.2/messages.txt
```

But with no success. Could you please help me out?

**Solution**

readFile() and $this->readFile() were different functions. The code was allright but it never got called. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\zdupp\ != C:/xampp/htdocs/zdupp/

Comment: Did you try replacing the value of `$this->path.$filename` with `/xampp/htdocs/zdupp/chat/1.2/messages.txt`? What are the permissions on that file? Does the user under which PHP is operating have read and write permissions? This is still relevant under Windows

Comment: see what is in `echo $location`

Comment: @Anigel forward slash works in PHP windows path for backslash

Comment: By the way, @Anigel Windows doesn't care whether your path has `/` or `\`. I just tested it and it works fine either way. If you use `\` you need to escape it.

Comment: kk my bad, I don't use windows as a server so that was news to me

Comment: this isn't really an exception, just a warning. you have to write your own exception if you want it to throw at this place

Answer (score 1):

Your function is defined as [`private`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

```
private function readFile($fileName)
```

Code outside of *that* class won't have access to directly call `private` functions inside it.